# Extracting array headers and keep their order

Tags: arrays, powershell, azure, sorting, header

I wrote a function which create an XLS file from an array. Everything works well but I'm facing a problem when extracting headers from my array.

My headers are organized alphabetically after extraction, but I want to keep them in the same order as my input array.

```
function DoTheMagicExcel {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        <# Array to work on #>
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Array]$MyArray,
        <# Its Excel Sheet name #>
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [alias('Sheet')]
        [string]$MySheetName,
        <# Excel file name #>
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidatePattern("\.(csv|xls)$")]
        [alias('XlsFile')]
        [string]$MyExcelFile
    )
    Begin {
        <# Init them all #>
        $excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
        $excel.visible = $False
        $excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
        $XlsAlreadyExist = $False
        if (Test-Path $MyExcelFile) {
            Write-Output "Fichier Excel deja existant"
            $XlsAlreadyExist = $true
            $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.open("$PSScriptRoot\$MyExcelFile")
            $workbook.Worksheets.Add() | Out-Null
            $workbook.WorkSheets.item(1).Name = $MySheetName
            $MySheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($MySheetName)
        }
        else {
            $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
            $workbook.WorkSheets.item(1).Name = $MySheetName
            $MySheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($MySheetName)
        }
        $MyHeadercolumn = 1
        $StartRow = 2
    }
    Process {
        $MyArrayHeader = $MyArray | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'
        foreach ($header in $MyArrayHeader) {
            $MySheet.cells.item(1, $MyHeadercolumn).font.bold = $true
            $MySheet.cells.item(1, $MyHeadercolumn) = $header
            $MyHeadercolumn++
        }
        foreach ($ThisRow in $MyArray) { ......
```

I mean this

```
$AllBcksummary[1] |ft -AutoSize

Server       RG     Environment Availability Vault   Status Regle                 Dernier Backup      Type
-------      --     ----------- ------------ ------  ------ -----                 --------------      ----
SEFRAPB0106  RG_AXL production  NOT SET      backup Healthy Policy14512-BDay-Prod 24/01/2018 19:22:15 AppConsistent


$MyArrayHeader = $AllBcksummary | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'

$MyArrayHeader |ft -AutoSize
Availability
Coffre
Dernier Backup
Environment
Regle
RG
Serveur
Status
Type
```

Then when I create my Excel I no longer keep its original order

```
foreach ($header in $MyArrayHeader) {
            $MySheet.cells.item(1, $MyHeadercolumn).font.bold = $true
            $MySheet.cells.item(1, $MyHeadercolumn) = $header
            $MyHeadercolumn++
        }
```

Comment: If you use a `Select` statement, put the header names in the order you want before piping to a table or an export command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick :)

```
$AllBcksummary.psobject.properties | select Name
```

From [How to get powershell object properties in the same order that format-list does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361418/how-to-get-powershell-object-properties-in-the-same-order-that-format-list-does) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Almost :)

```
$AllBcksummary.psobject.properties | select name

Name
----
Capacity
Count
IsFixedSize
IsReadOnly
IsSynchronized
SyncRoot
```

but adding index 0 do the trick !

```
$AllBcksummary[0].psobject.properties | select name

Name
----
Serveur
RG
Environment
Availibility
Coffre
Status
Regle
Dernier Backup
Type
```

Thanks guys